# Why don't my Tasks show in the Visual Studio Tasks window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating some Tasks using this code:

```
    private Task PollSomething()
    {
        return Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                while (!_cts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(200))
                {
                    var result = await _channel.DoSomethingAsync();
                    DoSomethingWithResult(result);
                }

                if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    throw new TaskCanceledException();

            }, _cts.Token);
    }
```

When I test the code everything works as expected, but when I run it in the debugger I cannot visualise the tasks using the Tasks windows (previously known as the Parallel Tasks window). I can see the threads just fine.

What might be causing the tasks not to be visible?

P.S. I'm using R# test runner and NUnit to execute this.

Comment: Might not be supported. Did you try using MSTest runner?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: No, did not try the MSTest runner. Will give it a go.

Comment: Is it because of the async void lambda?

Comment: I tried this in MSTest and have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there's an Visual Studio setting: "use managed compatibility mode" which fixes this.